# R: Set different space between pairs of dots in a dotplot

Tags: r, plot

I have a vector (data) with 5 values (hours) and I want to create a dotplot with different spaces between pairs of dots. I have written the following code trying to set different spaces between each pair of dots using the at keyword, in order not to get  the same space between each pair of dots, but I get the following error. I am new to R and I don't understand what I am doing wrong, could someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

```
print(data)
d <- c(1 , 2 , 4, 4, 5)
stripchart(as.vector(data$V1,mode='numeric'),
 at= d,
 col="red",
 pch=1
)
     V1
1 17:03
2 17:05
3 17:20
4 17:20
5 17:25
Error in stripchart.default(as.vector(data$V1, mode = "numeric"), at = d,  : 
  'at' must have length equal to the number 1 of groups
```

Comment: You can define each point's y-value by `stripchart(data ~ d)`